# Adding Row in DataGrid View using C# [WIndows Form]

Tags: c#

I am making a C# windows application where i have to add information in the grid view rows as i get them from network.

Here is Pseudocode about what i am doing.

```
while(getting info from network until there is no more info)

{

  // here i have to add the info in data grid, how i should do that?

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at

- [Walkthrough: Creating an Unbound
  Windows Forms DataGridView
  Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3ce6k8.aspx)
- [C# DataGridView Tips and Secrets](http://dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tips)
- [Programmatically Adding Rows to a
  Grid](http://en.csharp-online.net/Presenting_Data_with_the_DataGridView_Control_in_.NET_2.0%E2%80%94Programmatically_Adding_Rows_to_a_Grid)
- [adding rows to a data grid view](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic39260.htm)